# Why does my worklight project build/deploy much slower than coworkers?

Tags: performance, mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I just recently installed worklight in Eclipse in order to work on developing an iPad app, but I noticed it takes me significantly longer to build and deploy compared to the other developers. The others take rougly 5-7minutes each build while mine takes about 25-30 minutes. I am not sure what could be the reason and was hoping for some suggestions on what it may be?

I was told that in the build process worklight copies the contents of your projects to another directory on your machine, and I think the location of that directory might be the issue, but I am not sure how to check to see where this is happening.

**Edit:** To give more details as requested:

Both my machine and my coworkers machine are running Windows 7 Enterprise, with Intel dual core and 8G of RAM.

The workspace containing the project is located locally in the base of the C: drive but user profile files/folders such as My Documents are stored on a shared network drive. The project itself is 143mb.

Comment: You haven't added any information about yours and your co-workers development environment (machine, OS, etc, shared network drive?...), nor about the amount and size of files in your project. The larger the project, the longer the build will take. I can assume many things, but w/out proper information there cannot be a proper answer.

Comment: Same project, same Eclipse version, same Worklight version, same machines for all? Are you building anything different than your team members?

Comment: Yes, we are building the same version of the product with the same version of Eclipse and Worklight.

Comment: Does the project contain more environment other than the iPad environment? If yes, are you performing Build All and Deploy, or Build  Environment and Deploy?

Comment: Yes it contains an iPad enviornment and a mobilewebapp environment , but I am just doing the Build Environment and Deploy on iPad environment, which is the same way my coworkers do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix my own problem, worklight was using a .wlapp which was stored on my shared network drive. By changing the TEMP and TMP environment variables to a folder which is for sure local, such as C:\TEMP, worklight then accesses only local files great speeding up the build proccess.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge there are few factors that influence build time:

- Size of the Project (eg. 100MB)
- Number of Files in the Project (eg. 1200 files)
- Your environment got into a strange state.
- Some one reported performance issues [with adding new Java code](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14931032).
- Hardware

You can try:

- Lower the size of your project by removing unnecessary files, compressing images using [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression), etc.
- Concatenate resources like JS and CSS files.
- Try to use resources hosted on other servers, at least for development, for example:

  < script data-dojo-config="async: 1"
              src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js">

  < script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
- Try creating a new Workspace and importing your project or removing (back up first!) the project's metadata directories and files (`Workspace/WorklightServerHome`, `bin/`). You may have a some success removing and re-creating the native environment folders. There's also a `-clean` flag [you can pass to eclipse](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html).