# Is there any way to exclude library folders in worklight build-process?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using sencha touch.
This library is huge, more than 25MB, 2500 files.
So the build process is slow.

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896460/why-does-my-worklight-project-build-deploy-much-slower-than-coworkers), we should minify the library to make build process fast.
But If I minify this library, debugging gets harder.

I don't modify this library. So after first build, worklight also doesn't need to do something for this library in build-process.
Is there any way to exclude library folders in build-process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, the Studio/CLI tools do not provide the ability to not-rebuild certain artifacts in a build process. Each build request will re-request all artifacts and re-generate the resulting .wlapp/native folder.

Sounds like a good feature request: developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help

On a personal note: I would just not use Sencha :-) in a world where you have jQuery Mobile, Bootstrap, Ionic, etc...